# Error al calcular promedio de N notas

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

tengo un problema cuando quiere calcuar el promedio de N notas, en consola me aparece NaN, les dejo mi codigo para que vean como es que lo tengo armado

```
let alumnos = 2;
let notas = 3;
let promedio;
let calificacion;


for( let i = 0; i < alumnos; i++){

    let nombre = prompt(`Ingrese el nombre del Alumno: ${i}`);
    let apellido = prompt(`Ingrese el apellido del Almuno: ${i}`);

    console.log(`\t\t${nombre}` + " " + `${apellido}`)

    for( let j = 0; j <= notas; j++){
    calificacion = Number(prompt(`Ingrese la calificacion del alumno: ${nombre} ${j}`));
    promedio = (promedio + calificacion) / notas

    console.log(`\t\tSus calificaciones: ${calificacion}\n`)
    
}

    console.log(`${promedio}`);    
    console.log('\n\n')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vas a utilizar la variable promedio para almacenar la suma de los números, necesitas inicializarla con 0, porque al hacer la primera suma (promedio + calificacion), está sumando un número con una variable declarada; pero sin inicializar (que es undefined), y un undefined + un número, regresa NAN

```
let alumnos = 2;
let notas = 3;
let promedio = 0;
let calificacion;


for( let i = 0; i < alumnos; i++){

    let nombre = prompt(`Ingrese el nombre del Alumno: ${i}`);
    let apellido = prompt(`Ingrese el apellido del Almuno: ${i}`);

    console.log(`\t\t${nombre}` + " " + `${apellido}`)

    for( let j = 0; j <= notas; j++){
    calificacion = Number(prompt(`Ingrese la calificacion del alumno: ${nombre} ${j}`));
    promedio = (promedio + calificacion) / notas

    console.log(`\t\tSus calificaciones: ${calificacion}\n`)
    
}

    console.log(`${promedio}`);    
    console.log('\n\n')
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias Jorge, ya pude encontrar la solucion al problema luego de investigar un poco por internet, no sabia que tenia que inicializar la variable con CERO, como vengo de C pongo int numero y listo jajaj, muchas gracias por responder.